# i want to get rid of some path using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My url appears something like this 
https://sabaclothingscom.000webhostapp.com/sabaclothings/

https://sabaclothingscom.000webhostapp.com/sabaclothings/contacts

> i want to get rid of this ==>    `.000webhostapp.com/sabaclothings/`

so that my url should appear like this

```
https://sabaclothings.com/     <=== index


https://sabaclothings.com/contacts
```

i have successfully removed `.html` extension using this code ===>

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

please help me thanks in advance..

Comment: how do you think the numerous DNS servers across the glob resolve `sabaclothingscom.000webhostapp.com` to `sabaclothingscom`, by just changing some settings in your server? you may need to buy a domain with that name and I don't think that is currently possible (wrong domain name structure)

Comment: sorry for the typo

Comment: i have bought a `domain` called `sabaclothings.com` from `godaddy` but i don't have money for hosting so i opted `00webhost` which is free.  `but i want to point my domain with the purchased name, removing 000webhostapp.com `? how is this possible?

Comment: now that is not a stackoverflow question. I think 00webhost has info on how to do that [How do I point my existing domain to your nameservers?](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/how-do-i-point-my-existing-domain-to-your-nameservers-39). I am voting to close this question. And if you get into trouble with the above FAQ please post the question to [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The `.000webhostapp.com` part is the "host" or "domain" part of the URL.

You can NOT get rid of the "domain" part with `rewrite` rules.

You can get rid of that domain by owning your own domain and pointing the domain at the IP of your web-server in a DNS (Domain Name Server). You will then need to configure the web-server to accept the domain.

The result would still be something like `sabaclothings.com`, not `sabaclothingscom`.